# Changing one view to another

Tags: iphone, view

Anyone know of any example or codes which i am able to input so that a view which is the menu of my game is able to start the game on clicking start game button? Its like from menu view to the game view.

I had already done up the game just need my menu to link to the game. Thanks alot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're not using a game engine, you could use a UINavigationController and just use pushViewController:animated: You could also use an Animation block and addSubview:

These are very elementary principles, how did you manage to finish an entire game without learning about view hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UINavigationController to manage switching to/from the game and the menu. Alternatively, you can use UIAnimation to fade one in, while the other fades out, or move one view off-screen while the other moves on-screen. What sort of effect were you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a UINavigationController since you can add sub views to the main window as well.

Check out this tutorial for a good example. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20100102064245/http://icodeblog.com/2009/03/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-3-splash-screen/

Comment: link is dead and that makes this barely an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways which I know. First is on the click of the button you need to call the view to which you want to navigate as:

```
[self presentmodalviewcontroller:gameview animated:yes]
```

This just overlaps the view on another view. `gameview` is the view to which you want to navigate, and do remember to make its object by allocation before using the above line.

Another good way is to use `uinavigationcontroller` which push and pop the view and is the good practice. Allocate the navigation controller with `rootviewcontroller` which is your present view. To navigate just use:

```
[self.navigationcontoller pushviewcontroller:gameview]
```

and to pop the view to come back to the previous view you just need to use:

```
[self.navigationcontroller popviewcontroller animated:yes]
```

Congrats for completing your game application.